# Set out for a trip vs Set out on a trip?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm confused whether do we use *for* or *on* with the phrase set out?
Like,
I'll set out for a trip to Philadelphia.
I'll set out on a trip to Philadelphia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of 'for' implies prior to. For example,

> He set out for a boat trip to Alaska by flying Seattle.

Answer (score 0):

You set out **on** a trip, journey, errand, etc.

You set out **for** a destination.

> He set out on a trip to Philadelphia.
>
> He set out for Philadelphia.